# Bash array as argument inside of screen

Tags: arrays, bash, function, loops, gnu-screen

The below code is is not working  as I expect it to. I might be because I am doing this all wrong but I think it may be a quoting issue.

```
    #!/bin/bash 

    IFS=$'\n' 
    fortune_lines=($(fortune | fold -w 30))
    Screen_Session=$(mainscreen)
    Screen_OneLiner=$(screen -p 0 -S ${Screen_Session} -X stuff "`printf "say   ${fortune_lines[@]}\r"`")

    for var in "${Screen_OneLiner[@]}"
      do
        echo "${var}"
    done
```

I think I am not quoting something correctly because when I attempt to execute this. I get..

```
    line 5: mainscreen: command not found
    [screen is terminating
```

Essentially I am attempting to add this function (that works)

```
    IFS=$'\n' 
    fortune_lines=($(fortune | fold -w 30))
```

To this screen one liner

```
   screen -p 0 -S ${Screen_Session} -X stuff "`printf "say   ${fortune_lines[@]}\r"`"
```

Then have it loop the array

```
    for var in "${ArrayName[@]}"
   do
      echo "${var}"

   done
```

So I am not sure how far I am away (in code) to what I am trying to do. Any help would be great.

Comment: I managed to get this to work... https://gist.github.com/4006586

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

I managed to get this to work... [gist.github.com/4006586](http://gist.github.com/4006586) – user1787331

Answer (score 0):

This line is problematic

```
Screen_Session=$(mainscreen)
```

You are using command substitution here, so if `mainscreen` is not a valid command, you'll get `command not found` error.

Maybe you mean to use braces instead of parentheses?

Comment: I applied you change.  (Thanks BTW!) Things seem to be expanding correctly, BUT the loop only prints the first line in my array and not the entire index. Any suggestions?

Comment: The loop is correct. I'm guessing `Screen_OneLiner` contains a single string instead of being an array. Enclosing the `$(..)` in parentheses might help.